# error en select mysql c#

Tags: c#, mysql

tengo el siguiente metodo que consulta un rango de fechas y devuelve un correo asociado a un cliente

pero al ejecutarlo de la aplicacion no devuelve nada pero si lo ejecuto desde la linea de comando de mysql si funciona

```
  DateTime actual = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime fechaprimera = Convert.ToDateTime(actual, new CultureInfo("es-ES"));

                DateTime tiempo = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(tiempo, new CultureInfo("es-ES"));
                fecha = fecha.AddMonths(1);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT b.correo_empresa FROM tb_extintores a INNER JOIN tb_empresa b ON a.rut_cliente = b.rut_empresa WHERE a.fecha_vencimiento BETWEEN '"+fechaprimera+ "' AND '"+tiempo+"'", conexion.obtenerConexion());
```

si ejecuto esta linea en mysql extrae los datos

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.correo_empresa FROM tb_extintores a INNER JOIN tb_empresa b ON a.rut_cliente = b.rut_empresa WHERE a.fecha_vencimiento BETWEEN '2017-11-29' AND '2017-11-30'
```

el metodo completo es el siguiente

```
    public void cargar()
            {

                try
                {
                    DateTime actual = DateTime.Now;
                    DateTime fechaprimera = Convert.ToDateTime(actual, new CultureInfo("es-ES"));

                    DateTime tiempo = DateTime.Now;
                    DateTime fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(tiempo, new CultureInfo("es-ES"));
                    fecha = fecha.AddMonths(1);

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT b.correo_empresa FROM tb_extintores a INNER JOIN tb_empresa b ON a.rut_cliente = b.rut_empresa WHERE a.fecha_vencimiento BETWEEN '"+fechaprimera+ "' AND '"+tiempo+"'", conexion.obtenerConexion());

                    using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            //Este if hace que en todas las iteraciones salvo en la primera, se añada una coma ',' antes de el siguiente texto
                            if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Append(",");
                            sb.Append(dr["correo_persona"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    txtpara.Text = sb.ToString();
                    conexion.obtenerConexion().Close();
                }
                catch (Exception f) { 
MessageBox.Show(f.Message + f.StackTrace, "errror tipo 11");
}
            }
```

solución:

```
public void cargar()
        {

            try
            {


                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                {

                        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT b.correo_empresa FROM tb_extintores a INNER JOIN tb_empresa b ON a.rut_cliente = b.rut_empresa WHERE a.fecha_vencimiento BETWEEN @inicio AND @fin", conexion.obtenerConexion()))
                        {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inicio", DateTime.Now.Date);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fin", DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(1));


                        using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                //Este if hace que en todas las iteraciones salvo en la primera, se añada una coma ',' antes de el siguiente texto
                                if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Append(",");
                                sb.Append(dr["correo_empresa"].ToString());
                            }
                        }

                        txtpara.Text = sb.ToString();

                        conexion.obtenerConexion().Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception f) {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes unos cuantos problemas.

Primeramente, parece que en tu consulta, tu intención era de usar `fechaprimera` (ahora) y **`fecha`** (1 mes en el futuro). Pero en vez de eso, estás usando `fechaprimera` (ahora) y **`tiempo`** (ahora). Esto es un problema, porque ambas variables contienen `DateTime.Now`.

Segundo, no entiendo porque le haces tantas conversiones a las fechas. Esto no es necesario.

Y finalmente, aunque técnicamente puedes lograr hacer consultas concatenando variables directamente en el SQL, nunca hagas eso, en particular con fechas. Te expones a error sutiles y a la inyección SQL.  Usa parámetros:

```
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT b.correo_empresa FROM tb_extintores a INNER JOIN tb_empresa b ON a.rut_cliente = b.rut_empresa WHERE a.fecha_vencimiento BETWEEN @inicio AND @fin", conexion.obtenerConexion()))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inicio", DateTime.Now);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fin", DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1));

    using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

Adicionalmente, algo que repito siempre que lo veo, no es buena práctica usar conexiones globales. A evitar también.

Comment: lo cambie pero de igual manera no me extrae ningún dato. carga la variable 

inicio = 29-11-2017 18:45:34

fin = 29-12-2017 18:47:48

y el formato de la base de datos es 

2017/11/29

como puedo pasar la variable con ese formato sin la hora.

Comment: osea el select que realiza a la base de datos va de esta forma:

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT b.correo_empresa FROM tb_extintores a INNER JOIN tb_empresa b ON a.rut_cliente = b.rut_empresa WHERE a.fecha_vencimiento BETWEEN '29-11-2017 18:45:34' AND '29-12-2017 18:47:48'

Comment: Para quitarle la hora, le agregas una llamada a `.Date`: `DateTime.Now.Date` y `DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(1)`

Comment: por eso no me devuelve ningún dato pero si saco la hora si lo devuelve.

Comment: Estás usando parámetros como te lo mostré, o sigues concatenando la fecha directamente en la cadena SQL?

Comment: lo agregue como usted me dijo usando parámetros. tenia que pasarle solo la fecha con DateTime.Now.Date como me dijo, gracias. lo marco como respuesta.